# SharePoint Webhooks: SPExperimentalFeatureException

Tags: spfx

I am getting the below `SPExperimentalFeatureException` while following the SharePoint Webhooks.

> The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment.

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks

I am using the developer tenant as I can create/deploy the the SPFx webparts on the same tenant.

Is there a way to check if webhooks feature is enabled on my developer tenant?

Comment: Can you go to your tenant admin settings and opt in to early features?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69382)

Comment: 'Preview features' are enabled on my tenant.